# Why is this clone needed?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm learning Rust and creating a very simple application using Rust and Gtk:

```
extern crate gtk;

use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{Window, WindowType, TextView, TextBuffer, timeout_add_seconds};

fn make_window() {
    let window = Window::new(WindowType::Toplevel);

    let textview = TextView::new();
    window.add(&textview);

    let buffer = match textview.get_buffer() {
        Some(x) => x,
        None => panic!("Textview did not contain a buffer."),
    };

    buffer.connect_changed(move |buffer: &TextBuffer| {
        let b = buffer.clone(); // Why is this clone needed?
        timeout_add_seconds(1, move || {
            let ref buffer = b;
            Continue(false)
        });
    });
    window.show_all();
}

fn main() {
    if gtk::init().is_err() {
        println!("Failed to initialize GTK.");
        return;
    }

    make_window();
    gtk::main();
}
```

I am confused why that `buffer.clone()` is needed right before the inner closure.

If I leave it out, I get an error about lifetimes. But as far as I know, with or without clone, both have the same lifetime. So why does one work and one doesn't?

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:18:17
   |
18 |         let b = buffer; // Why is this clone needed?
   |                 ^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 17:54...
  --> src/main.rs:17:55
   |
17 |       buffer.connect_changed(move |buffer: &TextBuffer| {
   |  _______________________________________________________^ starting here...
18 | |         let b = buffer; // Why is this clone needed?
19 | |         timeout_add_seconds(1, move || {
20 | |             let ref buffer = b;
21 | |             Continue(false)
22 | |         });
23 | |     });
   | |_____^ ...ending here
note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected &gtk::TextBuffer, found &gtk::TextBuffer)
  --> src/main.rs:18:17
   |
18 |         let b = buffer; // Why is this clone needed?
   |                 ^^^^^^
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the type `[closure@src/main.rs:19:32: 22:10 b:&gtk::TextBuffer]` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/main.rs:19:9
   |
19 |         timeout_add_seconds(1, move || {
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But as far as I know, with or without clone, both have the same lifetime.

This is not quite true. If you clone a variable, you now have two versions of the variable. Each can be owned by a different owner and thus both can have a different lifetime. That's exactly what's happening in your case, it's just a bit hidden -- thanks to closure magic.

Let's look at your code again (I changed a few variable names to refer to them unambiguously later):

```
buffer_a.connect_changed(move |buffer_b: &TextBuffer| {
    let b = buffer_b.clone(); // Why is this clone needed?
    timeout_add_seconds(1, move || {
        let ref buffer_c = b;
        Continue(false)
    });
});
```

Here, the variable `b` is created by cloning and first lives in the outer closure (it's a local variable there). But then it is used inside the inner closure which is a `move` closure. As such, `b` is moved *into* the inner closure which then *owns* the `TextBuffer`. Yes: the inner closure owns the buffer `b`. This means that `b` lives exactly as long as the closure does; *independent* from the original lifetime!

To make sure we understood everything, just check the types of various variables:

- `buffer_a`: type `TextBuffer`
- `buffer_b`: type `&TextBuffer` (*probably* borrowed from `buffer_a`)
- `b`: type `TextBuffer` again (we cloned `buffer_b`, with the `clone()` signature of `clone(&T) -> T`)
- `buffer_c`: `&TextBuffer` again (borrowed from `b`)

This is further mystified by the `let ref buffer = b;` line. It's more idiomatic to write `let buffer = &b;` (both versions do the same thing).

And why exactly does Rust complain if we don't clone? The inner closure is required (by [`timeout_add_seconds()`](https://docs.rs/gtk/0.1.2/gtk/fn.timeout_add_seconds.html)) to *be* `'static` (more formally: "to meet the `'static` requirement). This means the closure can't reference anything that doesn't live forever (`'static`). If we don't clone, the inner closure would reference `buffer_a` which doesn't live forever.

Comment: It may be helpful to show the types of the various `buffer` variables (presumably the outer one is owned, the closure argument is a reference, then the `b` is owned again. Also might be worth checking to see if the inner closure might be called after the outer closure has exited.

Comment: So if I understand this right: the connect_changed closure will get called with a reference to a TextBuffer. The code that executes that callback owns that TextBuffer and that's why I can't move it inside the closure. But a clone is perfectly fine since it got created inside the closure and so is owned by it?

Comment: @Mew I think you understood it. I just added more explanation, hopefully making it clearer.